# Testing spring repositories

Tags: spring, testing, junit, integration-testing, spring-test

In the Spring Data I have found very helpful interface called JpaRepository. Because I need more functionality I decided to create my own interface of repository:

```
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    public <TA, TV> int deleteBy(SingularAttribute<T, TA> attr, TV val);
}
```

As you can see this is a generic interface. It works fine, but I would like to know how I can test it? Of course I can write integration test for each concrete repository but I am looking for better way.

Answer (score 0):

As usual with testing, you should make sure you know what you're testing. Find answers to these questions:

1. Do you want to test the underlying database?
2. Do you want to test the Spring Data repository connector for this respository?
3. Do you want to test whether your code calls the correct methods on the interface?

Doing #1 is useless: The database vendor has already run thousands of tests on its product. There is rarely a reason to do this effort again.

Doing #2 is useless unless you suspect a bug in the code for Spring Data.

Which leaves us with #3. Use a mocking framework to make sure the method is called at the appropriate places (and maybe check the arguments, too).

That way, you can make sure your code behaves correctly.

If you notice the framework throwing errors or you notice that objects aren't deleted correctly, you can add more tests. But most of the time, this won't happen because of bugs in the database or Spring Data. Instead, your code won't call `deleteBy()` or it will call the method with the wrong arguments.